# How to make a background image responsive and show on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, web

I've managed to get a background image to display on desktop devices and be responsive, however when I view the site on a mobile device the background image doesn't show up.

Heres the code I have so far:

```
#intro{ 
background: url(../img/trees.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/trees.png', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/trees.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Fiddle or it didn't happen

Comment: check your media queries..may be in mobile version it is hidden for responsive reason..or show fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

insert this to your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

change `background-size to 100vh` for the height and `100vw` for the width

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background: url(../image/background.jpg) no-repeat fixed top center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: so where you want to apply this??

Comment: `#intro {
  background: url(../img/trees.png) no-repeat fixed center;`

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I've incorporated this and the background resizes as I change the size of the window on a desktop which is fine. But if you view the site on a mobile device you can see that the background image height doesn't change sufficiently

Answer (score 0):

use `#intro{ background-size:100% 100%;}`